# Javascript interpretes 0 as null

Tags: javascript, spring, angular, enums

I have a `spring` endpoint that returns an `Enum` called `StatoPagamentoEnum`:

**Backend enum**

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY)
public enum StatoPagamentoEnum {

    DA_PAGARE(0),
    PARZIALMENTE_PAGATA(1),
    PAGATA(2);

    private int id;
    private StatoPagamentoEnum(int id) {this.id = id;}
    public int getId() {return id;}
}
```

**Backend endpoint**

```
public @ResponseBody MyEnum getStatoPagamento(){
   StatoPagamentoEnum statoPagamento = myMethod();
   return statoPagamento;
}
```

This endpoint is called by an angular service that maps an `Enum` as well:

**Frontend enum**

```
export enum StatoPagamentoEnum {
  DA_PAGARE = 0,
  PARZIALMENTE_PAGATA = 1,
  PAGATA = 2
}
```

**Frontend call to endpoint**

```
getStatoPagamento(idRichiesta: number): Promise<StatoPagamentoEnum> {
    const url = ...;
    return this.http.get<StatoPagamentoEnum>(url).toPromise();
  }
```

Everything works fine except when I try to read the enum value with id 0; in this case the angular service seems to read the 0 value as null. Is that possible that `javascript` interprete 0 as null value? Thanks.

Comment: Should ENUM not start at 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the problem was the line

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY)
```

This force to map the enum as an array, so the endpoint would return the position of the element inside the enum, and not its id.

1. I could replace the line with

   @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)

and in this case the endpoint would return o json object containing the element id, i.e. `{"id":1}`

2. I could remove completely the annotation, and in this case the endpoint would return the element id, i.e. `"DA_PAGARE"`

Both solutions work for me now. The javascript problems with the `0 -> null` implicit conversion remains though.

Answer (score 0):

the 0 in javascript is considered as `null`, can you try to declare your enumeration like this :

```
export enum StatoPagamentoEnum {
  DA_PAGARE = <number>0,
  PARZIALMENTE_PAGATA = <number>1,
  PAGATA = <number>2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`0` is a falsy value in JS, so there's every chance that the Angular service you're talking about has a check somewhere that looks like

`if(!theThingThatYouAreTalkingAbout)`

Which will behave the same way whether `theThingThatYouAreTalkingAbout` is `0` or `null` (or an empty string, or `undefined`).

Comment: JS needs to use if(theThingThatYouAreTalkingAbout === 0). Triple = checks the type is a number

Comment: Those are two separate statements. :D `===` does indeed do a full equivalence check, but the problem that the OP describes here is as a result of the fact that JS doesn't "need" to use that at all! :)